# Is there any input that would cause getline to fail in C++?

Tags: c++

Except for inputs like ctrl c etc.

To my understanding getline can only fail when reaching EOF, but I'm not very sure.

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/#return

Comment: Anything that cases the input stream to be in an error state.   This is expressed in terms of one or more of `std::ios_base::failbit`, `std::ios_base::eofbit`, or `std::ios_base::badbit` being set.     If none of those are set, `std::getline()` (or the `std::istream`s members named `getline()`) can cause either `eofbit` or `failbit` to be set.   For info on what the error states mean (for streams in general) look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate  For info on when `std::getline()` sets error states, look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: @Peter With that I believe you could get the question out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @Yunnosch    There's a bit more that I left out.    I'll look to expand the comment into an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is : Anything that causes the input stream to be in an error state.

An "error state" of a standard stream (derived from `std::istream`) is expressed in terms of one or more of `std::ios_base::failbit`, `std::ios_base::eofbit` (associated with end of file), or std::ios_base::badbit being set.    `ios_base` is a base class - via the templated `std::basic_ios` class - of all standard streams.

If none of those error states are set, `std::getline()` (or the member function of `std::istream` named `getline()`) can cause either `eofbit` or `failbit` to be set.

Conversely, `std::getline()` will respond to existing error states, and fail to read input if they are set.

For information on what the error states mean (i.e. what causes them for standard streams, in general) see [cppreference material on iostate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).

For information on when `std::getline()` sets the error states, see [cppreference material on `std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).   Similarly, for information on when the `getline()` member of standard input streams set error states, see [cppreference material on std::basic_istream::getline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).